# php delete element from object(stdClass)

Tags: php

I am trying to delete some elements of an array resulting from a fetch from a function in a class:

```
public function isChecked($db, $table, $id, $row_id)
{
    $answer = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $row_id =  $id")->fetch(); 

    var_dump($answer);
}
```

I get the following result:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["act_prim"]=> string(2) "12" ["act_id"]=>string(1) "1" ["a"]=> NULL ["b"]=> string(1) "1" ["c"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

I would like to remove the 2 first elements ("act_prim" and "act_id") from the array. But so far I dident succeed with any method.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: not sure if it'll work, but try unset($answer->act_prim). In any case, you should not do it this way. If you don't need those columns - don't select them! Use "SELECT column1,column2,..columnX FROM table" instead

Comment: Right, sorry that I dident see it, this question has indeed already been answered and the solution works great. Just to answer Marius, I did it this way because I have a lot of columns to select (around 50)  and only 2 to remove, and I dident find a way to do that query without having to rewrite all the column names.